# Find more than one string with Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, find, string

How to Find more than one string with Microsoft Office Excel?

For example, I am looking for the cells which is contained both strings Paul and John?

How to avoid to perform several finds by permuting arguments like that:

- first search: find Paul*John
- second find: search John*Paul

Imagine with n arguments ! !n permutations...

It seems to be impossible by the GUI. And what about macro or anything else?

Comment: please elaborate on the details of what you are trying to Find

Comment: You need to give more information. Currently, a valid answer would be "Use the search function twice", which may not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get all combinations of strings with the two words using two searches using the wildcard operator:

```
Paul*John - returns all instances of Paul somewhere before John
John*Paul - returns all instances of John before Paul
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's restricted to a single column then switching on AutoFilter and setting a custom filter might be the way to go.

If it's anywhere on the worksheet you're probably restricted to multiple searches